# How to check DKIM signature of incoming email in Java Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, dns, dkim

I am looking for a way to validate the DKIM signature of the incoming email.

I know how to do it in Java SE but it will use classes like `javax.naming.directory.DirContext` to get data from DNS server and this class is not white listed in App Engine.

Any idea how to communicate with DNS form Google App engine?

[There is a blog post that says:](http://blog.jhltechservices.com/2011/01/how-to-verify-dkim-is-working-for-your.html)

> Once you've configured DKIM, just send
>   an email from your Google Apps account
>   to:
>
> **dkim@dkim-test.appspotmail.com**
>
> within minutes, you should get back an
>   email that says "PASS" or "FAIL". If
>   your test passed, you're all set!

I tried it and it works!
It seems like a Google App Engine Application. How is it done?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm the author of the dkim-test app. Unfortunately I did not actually find a native way to do DNS queries in AppEngine. There's a feature request in the AppEngine issues tracker here:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=354

The way I got around this for dkim-test was to do a HTTP GET request to http://whatsmyip.us/dns_txt.php?host=google.com  (where google.com is the host I want to retrieve TXT records for).

Obviously there are some down sides here. dkim-test is entirely dependent on whatsmyip.us to work, should that service go down or they decide to block dkim-test, then it would break. Things would also break if they changed the format of the response.